# OpenGL: when and under what circumstances does shader patching occur?

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, shader

We currently experience some performance hiccups in an application that dynamically loads meshes into an application. The hiccups happen after the meshes/textures got uploaded (through glBufferData) and are rendered for the first time (the glRenderEelements call in that frame taking particularily long).

Our assumption was that the hiccup could be caused by lazy CPU-to-GPU transfer of either vertex/index data or texture data. But the subsequent hiccups also happen when we deactivate the texture upload and render without textures as well as if we issue a render call rendering the VBO's using a dummy shader right after upload (dummy render call is fast, but subsequent real rendercall in the next frame is still slow).

So, maybe shader patching is causing our hiccups.

The meshes get rendered with the same shader that meshes in previous frames have been rendered with and also have the same vertexformat (but of course new VBO's for vertices and indices are created and also new VAO's), so by my understanding shader patching should not happen in this case (only if a combination of shader, vertexformat and certain (which?) other gl states that have not been encountered before during the lifetime of the app are used shader patching should happen). Is this correct?

Is there any way to trace when and if the driver performs shader patching?

Any other ideas what could be causing these hiccups?

Comment: What do you mean by "shader patching?"

Comment: In the past, things like format conversion of vertex input as well as color conversion of the fragment output and blending operations were performed by fixed silicone on the graphics cards (for example, vertex format is uint while vertex shader calculates with floats). Nowadays (apparently) the shader programs are used to perform these operations - and the driver recompiles shaders to adjust for different conversions (and other gl_states that require adjusted operations) when it encounters a new configuration

Comment: What platform are you referring to? If PC, which graphics card?

Comment: @Columbo We are on Windows with an NVIDIA Geforce GTX 980 as target

Comment: I was hoping it would be iOS because you can infer the answer pretty well by the way that Apple's metal API works. As it is, I don't know too well for NVidia desktop, so I'll speculate in a comment instead of as a proper answer: I think that fragment shader patching is likely if you change the formats/numbers of colour, depth and stencil buffer attachments, if you change your blend mode/colour write mask and if you change your multisampling or alpha-to-coverage modes. I think that vertex shader patching is likely to occur if you change your vertex formats.

Comment: @Columbo thank you for that hint. Do you have any idea if this is happening only the first time such a new configuration is encountered, or each time the configuration changes? (i.e. is a version of the shader cached each time it gets recompiled? are these caches discarded at some point?)

Comment: Again, I'm speculating based on APIs I know more about, but I'd really expect it to be cached, so you'd only pay the first time.